# How to skip a test based on a self.skip_flag that I set using @pytest.mark.skipif

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to skip several test cases based on checks that I do from setup method. 
Setup should run only once and if `skip_flag` is set TRUE, then all the test cases should be skipped.

I have tried using skipif. but it couldn't help.

```py
class TestTmp:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def update(self,request):

        first_time = request.config.cache.get('first_time', True)
        if first_time:
            self.skip_flag = False
            request.config.cache.set('first_time', False)
            if True:
                self.skip_flag = True
            else:
                self.skip_flag = False

    def skip_test(self):

        if self.skip_flag:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @pytest.mark.skipif(skip_test, reason="Skip")
    def test_one(self):

        assert True

    @pytest.mark.skipif(skip_test, reason="Skip")
    def test_twp(self):

        assert False

    @pytest.mark.skipif(skip_test, reason="Skip")
    def test_three(self):

        assert True
```

Now, even when the `skip_test` is `false`, the test cases are getting skipped.
I cannot make call inside `skipif(skip_test(self), reason='Skip')` as `self` is not accessible

Comment: `pytest.mark.skipif` is a decorator. It will be evaluated once on module import and never again. You can skip tests using [`pytest.skip`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-skip) though, e.g. in your fixture `if condition: pytest.skip('this test was skipped because this and that')`

Answer (score 1):

As hoefling mentioned in the comment, the condition specified in the `skipif` decorator is evaluated during the test collection phase itself which happens before the actual test execution starts which means your `update` fixture has not yet been called and the `skip_flag` has not been set.

[`pytest.skip`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions) can be used to imperatively skip test execution during setup or test execution.

Also, since you want setup method to run only once, you can set the scope of the fixture to `session` scope.

```py
class TestTmp:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
    def update(self,request):

        first_time = request.config.cache.get('first_time', True)
        if first_time:
            request.config.cache.set('first_time', False)
            pytest.skip("Skip reason")

    def test_one(self):
        assert True

    def test_twp(self):
        assert False

    def test_three(self):
        assert True
```